# How to set position of label around a point in qgis according to a field

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm working on a `shape file` in `qgis` (2.8.4 Wien for Mac). In this file I have several points with about ten fields. What I'm interest in is to use two of these fields to set position of the label and the rotation of the symbol of the point: one field is the ***id*** of the point, the other one is the ***rotation***.

I represent the point symbol as a triangle with a little line, and I rotate it according to the *rotation* field (I have no problem with this).
The main problem is to place the label of the ID around the point in a specific position, according to the *rotation*, but without rotate it.

The rotation field contains, obviously, values from 0 to 359.

In the picture below, there is a sample of what I want to obtain:

[image: result sample]

I think is possible to use a offset function with sinus and cosinus, but the corresponding buttons are disabled on qgis interface.

There is a way to do this? Unfortunately this is a requirement of the work I'm doing.

Comment: Welcome! I found a similar question that might be helpful:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93268/qgis-2-2-rotated-labels-not-possible-any-more

Comment: It is a similar question, but I want to maintain unrotaded label. I want to adjust around the point. Thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the label Placement mode to "Offset from point", and then set a data defined override on the "Offset X,Y" field. This would require an expression like:

```
to_string("distance" * cos( "angle_radians" )) ||','|| to_string("distance" * sin( "angle_radians" ))
```

Where "distance" is your distance from point field and "angle_radians" the field containing the angle from the point in radians.

Note that for older QGIS versions "tostring" must be used instead of "to_string".

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Invalid expression.

Comment: Can you post your version of the expression?

Comment: Try the updated version

Comment: `2 * cos( "_rotation" *  $pi  / 180 ) ||','|| 2 * sin( "_rotation" *  $pi  / 180 )`

Comment: It works! typo error: to_string had to be tostring

Comment: I've just added a note about that. tostring was used in older QGIS versions.

Comment: I'm using 2.8.4 Wien that is the latest long term support version for mac.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the linked answer from @MaryBeth in the comment, for QGIS 2.12.1 (lyon) there's now a data defined rule for "quadrant" or the position of the label.

In the labeling dialog, select the "Placement" tab and then check the radio bullet for "Around point".

Then there is an option to set an expression for the "Quadrant".

[image: qgis quadrant option for data defined labelling]

If you check the description, it tells you what it expects as input.

In this case, it expects an int (an integer).

```
Data defined override
Active: no   (ctrl|right-click toggles)
Expected input:
int
[0=Above Left|1=Above|2=Above Right|
3=Left|4=Over|5=Right|
6=Below Left|7=Below|8=Below Right]
Valid input types:
string, int, double
Current definition :
undefined
```

You can see where each number represents a place in the quadrant.

So you just have to setup CASE ELSE type expression here that looks at the rotation values in your rotation field.

eg,

```
CASE
  WHEN "rotation" = 45 THEN 2
  WHEN "rotation" = 90 THEN 6
ELSE 0
END
```

Your `WHEN` statement can use ranges as well,

```
WHEN "rotation" >= 0 AND "rotation" <= 50 THEN ...
```

Comment: It's a good idea.
I'm stuck because I can set a quadrant function only for "offset from point" and not for "around point". It cause a little overlap of the label on the symbol.

Comment: @lypsyor If you set the quadrant using the "around point" option than you can adjust the "Distance" to something so that it doesn't overlap the symbol. How come you can't set the quadrant for "around point", is the quadrant option not there?

Comment: Yep, I know. I prefer solution provided by @ndawson, because it sets position in continuos mode around point and, moreover, is more simple to write.

Answer (score 2):

As SaultDon described, you can use an expression for the quadrant:

```
case
  when round(rotation / 360 * 8 + 1) % 8 = 0 then 1
  when round(rotation / 360 * 8 + 1) % 8 = 1 then 2
  when round(rotation / 360 * 8 + 1) % 8 = 2 then 5
  when round(rotation / 360 * 8 + 1) % 8 = 3 then 8
  when round(rotation / 360 * 8 + 1) % 8 = 4 then 7
  when round(rotation / 360 * 8 + 1) % 8 = 5 then 6
  when round(rotation / 360 * 8 + 1) % 8 = 6 then 3
  when round(rotation / 360 * 8 + 1) % 8 = 7 then 0
end
```

Edit: added `+1` offset since you seem to wish the label to be in the next quadrant clockwise.